# Problems with Yahoo API after authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, oauth, yahoo-api, hapi.js

I've been searching for answers for this for a while but I can't seem to find the answer. I've tried several things, all of which I'll list here, and hopefully someone can point me in the right direction.

First off, I've built a simple Node app using the Hapi framework. In addition, I'm using the Bell library, also from the Hapi guys, to authenticate with Yahoo and hapi-auth-cookie to set my session with the authentication results. This, from what I can tell, is working perfectly.

Bell, once the user is authenticated, provides me with a token and a secret.

The token looks something like this:

```
A=vvnxl1_FhCK6FPEFbIA.p_N8cSet7Ifmye.i3mWa6hrlh7fXecZhQvumjKSXPkRGfcj2BaFSmZCWPXeW67G8kqiS4G3Z7yBR
```

The secret looks something like this:

```
9e17917hsjf863c220c35f3f3385b6e4cd586c84
```

So once I authenticate and am redirected to my homepage, i have these two and a cookie is set. It's my understanding that I'm ready roll. I then try to hit the Yahoo API using the following URL:

```
https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/leagues;league_keys=328.l.5668/standings?format=json
```

The response to hitting this URL is:

```
{
"error":
    {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "description": "Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\"unable_to_determine_oauth_type\", realm=\"yahooapis.com\""
     }
 }
```

Obviously the URL I'm trying to hit is incomplete. However, I am unsure of what the required params are. I've been to the Yahoo docs 1000 times, but I can't seem to find this specific answer. All the examples there mostly relate to the authentication bit, which I should be done with. So, hoping I'd get lucky, I started trying to pass in the token and secret in the URL. In this one I tried API URL + token + secret + signature. The token and secret I'm using are the ones provided by Bell referenced above:

```
https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/leagues;league_keys=328.l.5668/standings?format=json&&oauth_token=A=tqq2L3D54ATsQZbgHB95b0ZyCj_kgq01R69vTulZ6lP9evhzddrIaksmd6u21fNSPFQ8WtVBsWr9GFk1zQtsw_OP4pKKaDKs2TxHlqwAYp4ZyIkthzPcSnJQka.J2THeK8BHC8eeisT4EeQpMqcDgefX6Hbb1CsQ_bD00ECd3AE.uGdF_6sm&oauth_secret=b5d2359f191cc72cfd318b5cf&oauth_signature=524a4f6e1407acd00a98f53973180%26b5d2359f191cc4c7d7d7bfd318b5cf
```

Now, it tells me that the token was rejected:

```
{
    "error": {
        "lang": "en-US",
        "description": "Please provide valid credentials. OAuth oauth_problem=\"token_rejected\", realm=\"yahooapis.com\""
    }
}
```

I also tried it without the signature first, in which case the error tells me that the signature is missing.

Any help here would be appreciated. From searching for the past week I see that the Yahoo API isn't the easiest thing to work with, but hopefully someone has some insight here as it seems that I'm so close. I hope I included all the info you need, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Once user is authenticated properly then you will have the "oauth_token" and the "oauth_token_secret", which you have as you mentioned.

Now, while trying to access the Yahoo API, you need to provide the "token" and "secret" as per oauth spec, so that Yahoo understands that you are allowed to access their APIs.

This is how oauth works, you can either provide the oauth information as part of "Authorization" header or query params with the url.

"oauth_token_secret" (with all other call information) should be used to generate the "oauth_signature" which yahoo will verify at their end. "secret" is not supposed to be sent as it is, while accessing their apis.

Note that, oauth information doesn't only involve the "token" and the "signature" but also the "nonce", "timestamp", "version", "signature_method", etc. All the information (along with secret) will be used to generate the signature which will then be passed to the yahoo as part of their api call.

Oauth docs can be found at http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc5849.pdf

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is where I currently stand. The url now has the timestamp, nonce, signature method, etc. I'm generating a base 64 string with the method and all of that together with new Buffer(myFullUrl).toString('base64'). The error im getting, now that I'm generating a proper signature (i think) is "consumer_key_unknown"... which doesn't make sense to me why that would be. I was using a different plug in the other day with the same key and it worked. Thanks again!

Comment: Are you providing the value for "oauth_consumer_key" param? "oauth_consumer_key" is expected for this call. You should have a yahoo apikey which you should use as a value for "oauth_consumer_key" while making api call.

Comment: I am. After fiddling with it a little more, looks like the signature is actually NOT correct. No longer getting the key unknown error, now getting a signature invalid error.

Comment: Now you are on the verge of getting it done. Just make sure you are using all the required params and values to generate the signature. That's it.

Comment: I ended up using the node-oauth plugin for it to take care of a lot of the heavy lifting. But it was still not working. Finally figured out my mistake. I was using https in the api call instead of http. wow.

Comment: Oauth has always been very tricky. Lot of nuances to take care of. Good that it worked for you finally.

Comment: I was getting the same error, and switched to OAUTH 1.0.  It works now.